# Is $(Tf)(x):=\int_0^x f(t)dt$ defined on $L^2([0,1])$ a finite rank operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

> Let $T:L^2([0,1])\to L^2([0,1])$ defined as $(Tf)(x):=\int_0^x f(t)dt$, is $T$ a finite rank operator?

Thank you for your help. I have the feeling it is. But How can I show it?

Comment: Consider the standard orthonormal basis for $L^2([0,1])$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams  don't know what's the standard orthonormal basis for $L^2([0,1])$...

Comment: @OlivierOloa: there's no such function.

Comment: @WillieWong Yes, Cauchy-Schwarz, we are on a compact set. Thanks!

Comment: The image of $T$ contains all $C^1$ functions which vanish at zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's pretty clear that $T$ does not have finite rank it's easy to see that $T$ *is* compact (hence the norm limit of a sequence of operators of finite rank).

For example, say $f_n$ is bounded. Passing to a subsequence we can assume that $f_n\to f$ weakly. Hence $Tf_n\to Tf$ pointwise. But $(Tf_n)$ is also equicontinuous. So $Tf_n\to Tf$ uniformly, hence $Tf_n\to Tf$ in norm.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the functions 
$$ f_n(t)=t^n \qquad (n\in\mathbb{N}). $$
Then $\{f_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is linearly independent, and we have
$$ (Tf_n)(x)= \int_0^xt^n\ dt=\frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}.$$
Thus, $\{Tf_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a linearly independent infinite set of vectors in $L^2([0,1])$, hence $T$ is not finite-rank.